# Expresso Store - fixed discount if total order > x kg

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, discounts

Is it possible to discount a fixed amount based on the weight of the total ordered items?

I have a store which sells fruits. 
Let's suppose fruit is available in different modifier_options

Oranges --product 
1 kg basket --modifier (2$ per kg.)
2 kg bag --modifier (1.90$ per kg.)
4 kg barrell --modifier (1.50$ per kg.)

Eg:
The customer orders 1 basket and 2 bags, for a total of 5kg. (no discount)
The customer orders 2 baskets and 2 bags, for a total of 6kg. (1$ discount)
Same applies if:
The customer orders 1 barrell and 2 bags, for a total of 6kg. (1$ discount)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Store does not currently support weight-based discounts, no.